# Changing coldfusion URL website that contain index.cfm

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, coldfusion, indexing

I am beginner at Coldfusion. I remade an entire website that was also coded in Coldfusion. As I am not an expert, I took some of the existing code to make the new website. The new one works all good, but I have a problem with the URL. When I type for exemple `thedomain.com/test`, it works fine, the htaccess makes it work as `thedomain.com/index.cfm?myvar=test`. But, when I directly enter `thedomain.com/index.cfm?myvar=test`, the URL stay like that. The page works also, but both pages are the same one and this is not good.

So my question is : How could I redirect that URL `thedomain.com/index.cfm?myvar=test` to that one `thedomain.com/test` ?

I made a lot of research, but I did not find a clear answer, except for [this answer](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/chapter/url-rewriting). It seems to be the exact thing I want to reach, but I do not undestand the htaccess terms and meaning... I do not understand how to use it.

Here is my .htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?i)^[\\/]CFFileServlet
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.cfm?variables=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^machineries-forestieres\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.machineries-forestieres.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The second part of the code is to redirect to «www» when there is none, because of a google translate API problem.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a ColdFusion question to me, it's a .htaccess question.

Comment: Please, edit and add your .htaccess code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are two methods for what you want to do:

### .htaccess

The trouble here is what you asked to do creates an infinite loop (redirect to /se/friendly/url/ if it's not se friendly, and because you want to be able to parse the string easily, redirect to (without displaying the url change, but that doesn't make a difference for the redirect loop) the `?traditional=url`.

What, I think, you have to do, is create a flag, like my stopht=1. If a user came upon a url that had stopht=1 anywhere in the parameters, the url will not change to se-friendly, it will stay `?traditional=url&stopht=1`.

Ideally, there is no reason the users should ever see stopht=1, because it's hidden from SE-friendly urls.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!.*stopht=1.*)uid=([0-9]+)&pid=([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.cfm$ /index.cfm/%1/View-Article/%2/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.cfm/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+) /index.cfm?stopht=1&uid=$1&pid=$3
```

So, converted to your index.cfm/myvar it would just be something like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!.*stopht=1.*)myvar=([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.cfm$ /index.cfm/myvar/%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.cfm/myvar/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+) /index.cfm?stopht=1&myvar=$1
```

### Javascript

Javascript (so yes, JQuery as well) have the ability to change the browser's url **to something on the same domain** without redirecting the user, via history manipulation.

Here, combined with cold fusion, you can do something like this

```
<cfoutput><script>
  window.history.pushState("", "", "/index.cfm/#uid#/#JSStringFormat(PageTItle)#/#JSStringFormat(pid)#");
</script></cfoutput>
```

You can't do this cross-domain (so I can't make my sites url say paypal.com to try to pretend to be paypal) but you can do it relative to your own domain.

Unfortnately, this code can't be demonstrated on this site or jsfiddle, but it's really really simple to plug in and causes no security concern within your own domain.

The downside is that it won't effect everyone because javascript can be disabled. The upside is that there's no overhead gain at all, and while htaccess has to use a generic title like my View-Article, javascript+cf can show the page title.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the javascript method worked for me. I tried the .htaccess method, without success. Maybe I did not use it correctly. But for the javascript, I used it with some conditions to be correctly done for my work and it works as I wanted.

Comment: @J-P-Dude Thanks :). You can select this as the answer if you like by clicking the checkmark above and below the arrows. Once you gain more than a reputation of 15, you can vote for answers as well. Have a good day!